# Can't convert string to float in PHP - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, type-conversion, laravel-5

I have a hidden field with a value. Since it's a hidden field my value is a string. In my database the value is stored as a decimal field with 2 point precision.

**View**

```
<tr class="grand-total">
   <th>Total incl. 21% BTW:</th>
   <?php $total = number_format($cartTotal, 2, ',', '') ?>
    <td><strong class="grey-color">&euro;{{$total}}</strong></td>
 </tr>

 <input type="hidden" name="total" value={{$total}}>
```

**Controller**

When my total is, for example, €10.95, I get €10.00.

Things I have tried:

```
(float)$request->total

floatval($request->total)

floatval($request->total * 1.00)
```

But these all return €10.

Comment: Your total is `10,95` or `10.95` ?

Comment: `10,95` is an invalid designation. Have changed to `10.95` as only valid reading. Edit pending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide a float number which uses **a dot to separate integer from decimals**, not a comma, so you must input `10.95` instead of `10,95`.

Obviously you can use str_replace if you still want to use commas :

```
$myNumber = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $myNumber));
```

Answer (score 4):

Although this doesn't directly answer the question, it will indeed solve it in a more long term way.

Consider storing money amounts *without* the decimal - so `$10.00` is actually stored as `1000` in your database.

You can also use built in functions within PHP such as [money format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) as long with setting your local currency to really nail this problem in the head.

[What are the downsides to storing money values as cents / minor units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934774/what-are-the-downsides-to-storing-money-values-as-cents-minor-units)

Comment: this is a good answer. I was considering it when building my app. But i didn't go for it because my calculations would be pretty complex . But maybe it should try it next time.

Comment: I think the more complex the calculations are, the further you should get away from floats, just my 2 cents (pardon the pun)